Mesh refinement in GMSH based on specific points
I am working with GMSH to do stepwise mesh refinement.
In each step I am generating a point cloud where I want to refine the mesh in the vicinity of each point. Is there a way to do a refinement based on how many points are in each area (as some sort of distance function)?
I am working with 2D meshes in planar structures and am importing the returned mesh in Matlab.
I am trying to achieve something with a distance Field and an overlaying Threshhold Field, but here I need to define the Meshsize in the vicinity of the points, it does not let me control the mesh based on how many points are in the area.

Field[1] = Distance;
Field[1].PointsList = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};

Field[2] = Threshold;
Field[2].InField = 1;
Field[2].SizeMin = lc/4;
Field[2].SizeMax = lc;
Field[2].DistMin = lambda/200;
Field[2].DistMax = lambda/100;

Field[7] = Min;
Field[7].FieldsList = {2,3};
Background Field = 7;


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
